# XMonad toggle window create/close

Tags: config, xmonad

I have a key bind that create a terminal window floating at the center of the screen.

```
runInCenterTerm :: String -> String -> X ()
runInCenterTerm t cmd = do
  r <- fmap (screenRect . W.screenDetail . W.current) (gets windowset)
  spawnAndDo (doRectFloat $ adjust r) $ intercalate " " [ t
                                                        , cmd ]

where
  adjust (Rectangle sx sy sw sh) = W.RationalRect x y w h
    where
      w = min (1200 / (fromIntegral sw)) 1
      h = min (600  / (fromIntegral sh)) 1
      x = (1 - w) / 2
      y = (1 - h) / 2
```

And I want that the same key bind close this window if it exists.

What is the best way to implement this behavior in XMonad?

I was thinking about setting a X property in the window and later query if a window have this property.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to re-implement the behaviour of a ([named](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.1/docs/XMonad-Util-NamedScratchpad.html)) [scratchpad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.1/docs/XMonad-Util-Scratchpad.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of behavior that I wanted. I finally implement something different using ExtensibleState to keep track of the window